# Phonegap error: Cannot find module

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to create a HelloWorld project but are experiencing an error

```
phonegap create C:\Desenv\PhoneGap\learn com.cassia.hello HelloWorld
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\cassiasantos>phonegap create teste com.cassia.hello HelloWord
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '..\..\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cassiasantos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\phonegap\lib\cordova\index.js:16:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have to install all the modules - at least this fix worked for me.

Use

```
sudo npm update -g
```

Found the solution in an [ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-cannot-find-module-bplist-parser/38551/4).

Answer (score 3):

this is phonegap bugs.
Here is temporary solution

```
Install cordova-lib under
../node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova
```

Goto ../node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova

Exec `npm install cordova-lib`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as yours. I just uninstalled and reinstalled NodeJS and that worked for me.

To uninstall NodeJS on Windows, goto Control Panel->Programs and Features. In the list of installed software, you will find NodeJS. Right click on NodeJS and uninstall it.

To reinstall NodeJS, visit their website. [click here](https://nodejs.org/en/) to visit their website and download the latest LTS version of NodeJS.

After doing this, check if you again have the same error. If you do, then run the command:

npm install -g phonegap

That should definitely fix your issue! Cheers!